# My div class:"title" doesn't appear to be centered even though div is margin:auto. How do I fix this?

Tags: html, css, web, margin

I set my `div` to be `margin:auto` and the `h1` inside should be centered but it is not. I do not know how to correct it and I have tried different things but none of them work. Please help. It does not appear centered.

```css
    body {
        background: #5D6D7E;
        color: white;
        font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    header {
        background: white;
        color: #3498DB;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }

    a {
        color: #D7DBDD;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    a:hover {
        color: white;
    }

    section {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    div {
        width: 100px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .title {
        /* Isn't centered  */
        font-size: 50px;
    }

    header,
    section {
        background: #2E86C1;
    }

    header,
    section,
    footer {
        padding: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="title">
        Brainstorm
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `text-align:center` BTW format your code it's atrocious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you created the rule `div { width: 100px; }`, which restricts the element in question to only `100px` `width`. Your element is indeed correctly center, just too big to fit within the 100px constraint.

Removing this rule shows the element centering as expected:

```css
body {
  background: #5D6D7E;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background: white;
  color: #3498DB;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

a {
  color: #D7DBDD;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover {
  color: white;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

div {
  /*width: 100px;*/
  margin: auto;
}

.title {
  /* Doesn't appear to be center  */
  font-size: 50px;
}

header,
section {
  background: #2E86C1;
}

header,
section,
footer {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="title">
    Brainstorm
  </div>
</section>
```

If you don't want to remove this rule for all `<div>` elements (which I would recommend), you can also simply set `width: auto` on `.title`.

Also note that you had some invalid HTML in your question, along with an extra leading `}` in your CSS -- I've corrected both of these in the above snippet.

Comment: am I still able to put a width on the div?

Comment: You are... though I would recommend against it. `<div>` elements are designed to be container elements, and occupy the full available `width` (`100%`) by default. If you're trying to restrict phrasing content like a title, you may wish to consider a `<span>` tag. Note, however, that inline elements (such as `<span>` by default) will automatically expand their `width` to contain their content, and not be any wider than said content. If you have a `background` on a `<span>`, it will only go to the edge for the text, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Every answer currently shows you how to center text inside a div, but none points out that you don't have any heading in your Markup.

divs don't have any semantic meaning, if you really want to have a heading then you should also use appropriate heading tags:

```
<section>
  <h1 class="title"> Brainstorm </h1>
</section>
```

CSS for this can be the same as for the div:

```
.title {text-align: center}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS. It should work

```
h1{
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Works!

**HTML**

```
<section>
  <div class="title">
    Brainstorm
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.title{
  text-align:center;
}
```